# bash: cannot remove directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell

I'm not able to remove the directory test:

```
$ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 www-data www-data 0 Nov  6 07:11 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 5 www-data www-data 0 Nov  5 13:57 ..
drwsrwsrwx+ 3 www-data www-data 0 Okt  4 07:28 test
$ sudo rm -r test
rm: cannot remove 'test/subdir with spaces': No such file or directory
$ sudo rm -r ./*
rm: cannot remove './test/subdir with spaces': No such file or directory
$ ls -al test
ls: 'test/subdir with spaces': No such file or directory
total 0
drwsrwsrwx+ 3 www-data www-data 0 Okt  4 07:28  .
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 www-data www-data 0 Nov  6 07:11  ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 0 Okt  4 07:28 'subdir with spaces'
$ sudo getfacl test
# file: test
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
# flags: ss-
```

What I'm doing wrong? How can I delete this directory? The directory is located at a mounted hetzner storage box.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the id of the user of the commands?

Comment: Add output of `id`, `stat test` and `lsattr test` to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sudo rm -rf ./test`if it doesn't work try to replace the current directory to a new one with the same name `sudo mkdir ./test` and then remove it again `sudo rm -rf ./test`.

Comment: sudo ```rm -rf ./test``` now worked ;-) I don't know, why, because I already used this command without success. Maybe it has something to do with the storagebox or a server reboot, which I did right before...